where to load arial.ttf font and any other font file from a trusted source
How can I load an arial.ttf file? I am using sdl_ttf.h for a project and since sdl_ttf only provides functions to open ttf files and doesn't come with font file preinstalled it is showing error that it is not able to open arial.ttf.
So I asked tabnine and it said that you have to load it externally and then add it in your working directory but it gave the link to Microsoft site for loading it, but i don't find any direct option for loading it there. I think it wants me to license. Is there any other trusted site or way of loading it?

Find a free font that you're allowed to distribute with your app. Arial isn't one, I believe. Try something from https://fonts.google.com/

ya thx @HolyBlackCat no issues regarding use of fonts other than arial i just wanna test my app, so any font will work thx for sharing this.

you can also try https://www.dafont.com/ it's a well-known font marketplace/download site. Most of the fonts there are free, but make sure to read the descriptions to see if they are free for commercial use.

Core fonts for the Web
Was a project providing a freely downloadable font-package including common fonts like Arial, Courier New, Georgia, Impact, Times New Roman etc.
As this project was discontinued in 2002 you only find inofficial archived download links. If you're running on a Debian based Linux distribution you may also use the ttf-mscorefonts-installer.
Please read the wikipedia entry for more details. From this article:

Program termination and software license agreement issues
The project was terminated in August 2002, allegedly because of frequent
EULA violations. A Microsoft spokesman declared in 2002 that
"Microsoft has also found that the downloads were being
abused—repackaged, modified and shipped with commercial products in
violation of the EULA." "Most users who wanted the fonts have
downloaded them already."[2][26][27] However, that same EULA allows
redistribution if the packages are kept in their original format (.exe
or .sit.hqx) and original filenames (e.g. times32.exe) and not used to
add value to commercial products.[1][28] As a result, these packages
are still available for download on third-party websites under the
terms of the original web fonts end user license agreement.


If a third party offering the fonts for download does not offer a copy
of the EULA, the legal status of such a download is questionable.

In other words, while ubiquitous fonts like Arial appear to be completely free they are also subject of proprietary licences (licenced by Monotype). You can download and install them for private usage (like testing purposes) but you shouldn't include them in commercial applications.
